# How to group column from imported csv file in php

Tags: php, csv

I have a csv file which has a many rows, like the following:

```
1992831, ID23, Ini barang, ini kode barang
1992831, ID24, Ini barang 2, Ini kode barang 2
1992832, ID23, Ini barang 3, Ini kode barang 3
```

From the above example, I want to filter the column with ID23, the result should like this :

```
1992831, ID23, Ini barang, ini kode barang
1992832, ID23, Ini barang 3, Ini kode barang 3
```

How can I do that in php?

Thanks for your feedback..

Comment: I removed the Oracle tag because your question is about PHP, not databases.

Comment: Do you want to _group_ or _filter_? For both you have to go through your dataset and check the ID value

Comment: sorry, i wanna filter..

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the data like this:

```
if (($handle = fopen($full_path, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        if ($data[1] == 'ID23') {
            //INSERT OR STORE ARRAY
        }
    }
}
```